# Doxygen: Can file members inherit a module grouping if they are in a file that is grouped?

Tags: doxygen

Lets assume I have a file, somefile.c. At the top of this file I have

```
/*!
* \file somefile.c
* \ingroup some_group
*
* \defgroup some_group Some Awesome Group
* \brief Module's description
* bla bla bla
*/
```

Within the body of this file I have some arbitrary number of functions, typedefs, variables, structs, etc. Right now I am having to go through and put a \ingroup in the documentation block for every single one of these. For the most part I group my modules by file (which I am sure the rest of the world does too). I have a few modules that have multiple headers and c files, and in those I do subgrouping.

Is there a way to configure doxygen to assume that I want every file member to inherit the module grouping of the file it is in?

Comment: No sure if I understand the problem completely but did you have a look at \addtogoup \{ and \}

Comment: Yeah, doing \addtogroup some_group, followed by a \{, with a \} at the end of the file does exactly what I want. Can you please post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required functionality can be obtained by using the command \addtogroup in combination with \{ and \}

Comment: [Here is a more detailed example of the above from Doxygen's manual](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdaddtogroup)